# Different ways to create objects in java

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I know this is very basic question but please read the full question first. Its bit confusing for me so I need all your help. 
We know that there are two ways of creating an object in java.

- use of "`new`" keyword and
- `class.forName()`.

But I came across some other ways also in a book to create an object which I am not able to understand. The keywords are

- newarray
- anewarray
- multianewarray

I am not getting any good study meterial on internet for these keywords. Please help me out.
I am posting the link here. Please read the first 2 lines.
http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/gcP.html

Comment: These are bytecode instructions for the JVM to create arrays, not the keywords in Java. You don't use them in code.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

Comment: 2) does not create objects, it loads the class. (which is an object itself but one of type `Class`)

Comment: http://java8.in/unit-2-prog-7-test-clone-method/ Ways to create object are listed here.

Comment: @zapl 2) returns the `Class` instance corresponding to the named class. Class itself is not an object, and the method call does not load it; it may *cause* the class to be loaded as an indirect effect of the class having been referred to for the first time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik How is a `Class` itself not an object?  http://ideone.com/RnPHZw

Comment: @zapl You are confusing things. `Class` is, well, a *class*, just like `String` is a class. `Class.class` is an instance of the  `Class` class, representing the `Class` class. `Class.forName(String)` returns an instance of `Class` and that instance itself *is not a class*.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Now you're confusing me :) But I think I understand what you mean: Instances of something are not classes, they are just instances. In case of instances of `Class` they represent a class while not actually being that class. They are just a handle to the abstract concept of a class (And I guess the actual class could be considered bytecode loaded by the JVM which is not part of the Class object)

Comment: @zapl Yes, on the Java platform a class is a low-level system resource which cannot be accessed directly; it can only be "talked about" via reflection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are not keywords: these are JVM bytecode instructions.

E.g. Java code `new int [3][2]` compiles into these bytecodes:

```
iconst_3
iconst_2
multianewarray [[I 2
```

Comment: ok thanks. my mistake. I misunderstood. Anyways thanks for your guidance. I will study about it.